# Apple Pay остается в состоянии обработки

Tags: apple, платежи, stripe, stripe-payments

Почему при оплате через Apple Pay мой платеж проходит, но модальное окно всегда остается в состоянии обработки. Как я могу закрыть это окно после успешной оплаты?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Please, translate to russian language. This is ru.stackoverflow

Comment: @alex I have done

Comment: thank you, but, if you're fluent in english, you have beautiful opportunity ask english section. They have a lot of people, we are just russians )